# . . . resolves to a package - JSP

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I have been trying to import a file from another project. To do that, I added the other project to current project by right clicking current project > properties > Java build path > Projects > Add.

Then I imported a class from the other project like this:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*, com.vl.csr.util.DatabaseUtil" %>
```

But when I run the project, I get runtime error saying `"com.vl.csr.util.DatabaseUtil"` resolves to a package.

I tried adding ";" at the end of import, as suggested somewhere else on stackoverflow, like:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*, com.vl.csr.util.DatabaseUtil;" %>
```

But, then, I get the error about mistake in import statement.

My complete code is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*, com.vl.csr.util.DatabaseUtil" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <table style="width:100%" border =3>
  <tr>
    <th>Booking ID</th>
    <th>CCA Sent (Yes/No)</th>
    <th>CCA Acknowledged</th>
    <th>Folio Received</th>

  </tr>

   <%
        Connection objCon = DatabaseUtil.getDbConnection();

        ResultSet objRs;
        PreparedStatement objPst;
        String q = "select * from booking_req_mst";
        if (objCon != null) {

                objPst = objCon
                        .prepareStatement(q);
                objRs = objPst.executeQuery();


        ResultSetMetaData metaData = objRs.getMetaData();
        while(objRs.next())
        {
            %>
                <tr>


                     <td>
                     <%= objRs.getString(1)%>
                     </td>

                     <td>
                     </td>

                     <td>
                     </td>                    

                </tr>
            <% 
        }
          }
    %>

</table> 
</body>
```

How do I resolve this?
Please help!
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It is not enough to add the other project (where the `com.vl.csr.util.DatabaseUtil` comes from) to the build path in Eclipse only, it has to be deployed to the servlet container as well, e.g. as a JAR file in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. As I don't know your projects' structure and what kind of build tool (ant, maven, gradle, ...) you use, I cannot tell more.

Comment: That would be something you could automate using the Deployment Assembly property page on the project.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a package with that name, even with a different case?

Comment: @Jozef, I created the WAR file for both  the projects  and added  them in WEB-INF/lib folder of current project. It still gives the same error.
And the build tool I'm using is 'ant'.

Comment: @nitind, I don't have any package with that name.

Comment: @Lemmy It has to be JAR, not WAR, file.